# get the list of values for a particular managed property

Tags: 2013, 2010, managed-property

I have a `managed property` created. When I use the default SharePoint search, it
creates a `KQL query` that looks something like below

```
http://site/search/pages/item.aspx?k=*#Default=["k":"*","r":[{"n":"String15","t":["\"#413342asd2335cddgeh\""],"o":"and","k":false,"m":null}]}
```

Now the `string15` is a managed property that we have created for `ContentType` (site column) of a page. It has values like news, blog, post, etc.

When I refine search and click on news, it adds `413342asd2335cddgeh` in the KQL and brings up the results.

How can I get the ID's of all the `ContentType` I have? for ex: `413342asd2335cddgeh` is the one for `"News"`

Is it possible to get them using API call? Where can I find them?

Comment: This is not an ID it is a encoded value of the text string (I think it is base64 encoding). So you need to base64 encode you values, preferably "on demand"

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by "on demand" ? 
I currently have values in javascript variables and I need to form a href link with parameters. I am planning to convert them to hex and form the href url for anchor tag and bind it.

Comment: Yes that would be what I meant with "on demand", to not hard code them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an ID it is a encoded value of the text string (I think it is base64 encoding). So you need to base64 encode you values, preferably "on demand" (not hard coding the converted values)